# Resetting Diff tool to use default in SourceTree 2.7.1 on Mac

Tags: git, macos, atlassian-sourcetree

Is there any way to reset external `difftool` to default in `Sourcetree`? 
I tried a custom option to make it use `Visual Studio Code` as the difftool  and it didn't seem to work. Here are the steps I followed
https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/Setup-Sourcetree-to-use-Visual-Studio-Code-as-External-Diff/qaq-p/685939

My git is configured to use Visual Studio Code. 
I want to reset `Sourcetree` to use default difftool  but I cannot seem to get any such option in the drop down menu for `Visual diff tool` option or `Merge tool` option.

Comment: So when you go to settings and choose the option for visual diff tool you see no options? May be best to uninstall and re-install sourcetree

Comment: Yeah, it does nothing and just ignores it. I will have to do that I guess :( . I am curious why it doesn't have a `use default` option in the dropdown